# Saving data from DB and then using it in body for API in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, web-api-testing, cypress-task

I am trying to save a token from DB and pass the token in the next API request in the body I have written the below code but it's not working, please help.

```js
it.only('Change Password', () => {
    cy.ResetPassAPI(globalThis.data.dradminemail);// this generates a token in DB
    const resetoken = cy.task(
      'queryDb',
      `select _Token from tokens WHERE _Member_Id = 25372 and _Token_Type = "resetPassword" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1`,); // saving the token from DB generate from above

    

    cy.request({
      method: 'PATCH',
      url: 'https://xxx/xx/xx/changePasswordWithToken',
      body: {
        confirmPassword: 'xxx',
        password: 'xx',
        token: resetoken,  //passing the saved token from database
        uid: 1234,
      },
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for `cy.task()`

Instead of

```js
const resetoken = cy.task(...)
```

it should be

```js
cy.task(...).then(resetoken => {
```

Full test:

```js
it('Change Password', () => {
  cy.ResetPassAPI(globalThis.data.dradminemail);
  const query = 'select _Token from tokens WHERE _Member_Id = 25372 and _Token_Type = "resetPassword" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1';
  cy.task('queryDb', query)
    .then(queryResult => {
      const resetoken = queryResult._Token;
      cy.request({
        method: 'PATCH',
        url: 'https://xxx/xx/xx/changePasswordWithToken',
        body: {
          confirmPassword: 'xxx',
          password: 'xx',
          token: resetoken,  
          uid: 1234,
        },
      });
    });
});
```

You probably don't need the token anywhere else, once the PATCH has been sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot its one part is working but my problem now is the reset token I am getting is also coming with a column name like {_Token: 'c474f281-271b-4448-a447-7b2eabc6fb1a'} when I am passing this in the body its invalid as I need to only pass the key and not the whole part. Can you please with that.

Comment: Essentially the results of the select query are returned in an object, to access it use the property notation `result._Token`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response I have tried the above but its not returning any token in the body pasting the request Body: {"confirmPassword":"cbrex1","password":"cbrex1","uid":25372}. I wont wondering if we can use slice or split.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. From what you said in the first comment, this should work.

Comment: Thanks, fody for all your help it finally worked using this result[0]._Token

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cypress.env()` for this.

```js
it.only('Change Password', () => {
  cy.ResetPassAPI(globalThis.data.dradminemail) // this generates a token in DB
  const resetoken = cy.task(
    'queryDb',
    `select _Token from tokens WHERE _Member_Id = 25372 and _Token_Type = "resetPassword" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1`
  ) // saving the token from DB generate from above
  Cypress.env('token', resetoken.slice(12,48))

  cy.request({
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: 'https://xxx/xx/xx/changePasswordWithToken',
    body: {
      confirmPassword: 'xxx',
      password: 'xx',
      token: Cypress.env('token'), //passing the saved token from database
      uid: 1234,
    },
  })
})
```

After Slicing:
[image: after slicing]

Comment: Thanks for the help but the request body its sending back looks like this 
Body: {"confirmPassword":"cbrex1","password":"cbrex1","token":[{"_Token":"d20a784d-9ca3-4b4f-bdfa-c35051c6d8d8"}],"uid":25372}
in token i only then string like "d20a784d-9ca3-4b4f-bdfa-c35051c6d8d8" but not the other part can you help me with that

Comment: Updated the answer with the `slice` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as an alias and then access it later with calling alias or using `this` keyword within `function(){}` instead of arrow function `() => {}`

```js
// use function{} instead of () => {}
it.only('Change Password', function() {
    cy.ResetPassAPI(globalThis.data.dradminemail)
    cy.task(
      'queryDb',
      `select _Token from tokens WHERE _Member_Id = 25372 and _Token_Type = "resetPassword" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1`,)
      // task returns token so we save it with alias
      .as('resetToken')

    

    cy.request({
      method: 'PATCH',
      url: 'https://xxx/xx/xx/changePasswordWithToken',
      body: {
        confirmPassword: 'xxx',
        password: 'xx',
        token: this.resetToken, 
        uid: 1234,
      },
    })
  })
```